# Create macro depending on counter at point of definition

Tags: macros, numbering, counters

I have a document with various numbered objects, e.g., term rewrite systems with numbered function symbols like this:

[image]

While I need a numbered output for these symbols (it should illustrate the output of an automated analysis - and in fact the variables will also be numbered in the end), in my examples they correspond to some semantical objects. So for the system in the picture I would have code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\initstate}{f_1}
\newcommand{\processstate}{f_2}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]

\end{document}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I would like to extend such a system by a new symbol which is not the last one (or if want to reorder the numbers), I need to change all the commands manually (e.g., if I add another symbol and use the command `\storestate` for the symbol `f_2`, then I need to change the command `\processstate` to `f_3`). So the example would then look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\initstate}{f_1}
\newcommand{\storestate}{f_2}
\newcommand{\processstate}{f_3}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,0) \to \storestate(x,y)\]

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\storestate(x,y) \to \processstate(y,x)\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]

\end{document}
```

What I would like to have is that the number in the commands is inserted depending on the order of command definitions (and not specified explicitly in the commands). So if I switch the order in which `\initstate` and `\processstate` are defined, their corresponding symbols should also switch their numbers. Likewise, if I add another command definition between the two existing ones, the numbers in all commands should be updated automatically. The number "assigned" to a command that way should not change anymore during usage of the new commands. So in the end, the code should look like this for the two examples (and produce the same output):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{funcsyms}
\setcounter{funcsyms}{1}
\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\processstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]

\end{document}
```

Second example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{funcsyms}
\setcounter{funcsyms}{1}
\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\storestate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\processstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,0) \to \storestate(x,y)\]

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\storestate(x,y) \to \processstate(y,x)\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]

\end{document}
```

So I would like to specify 4 things: the name of the new command, its definition before the number, the counter used for the number, and its definition after the number. The number should basically be the position of the corresponding command's definition, i.e., if I define the command `\initstate` first, its number should be 1. If this command is defined as the second command, its number should be 2 etc.

If I change the order of the command definitions in the last example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{funcsyms}
\setcounter{funcsyms}{1}
\numberedcommand{\storestate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\processstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,0) \to \storestate(x,y)\]

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\storestate(x,y) \to \processstate(y,x)\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]

\end{document}
```

The output should be:

[image]

If I just reference a counter in such a `\numberedcommand` and increase it, I will get different numbers in the several places where I use the new command. So that would not solve the problem. If I increase the counter between the definitions, I get the same number for all symbols. How can I define macros that automatically get numbered according to their point of definition (i.e., how to define `\numberedcommand` in the example above)?

Comment: `\processstate` should always print the name with the successor of the number appended to `\initstate`?

Comment: Also, what should `\storestate` do? Please, expand with some more examples of intended usage.

Comment: @egreg I added an example for the use of `\storestate`. What the semantics of these commands is, is irrelevant. What matters is that they produce output containing a number and this number should be set according to the position of definition of the command.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're after.

Comment: @egreg I added another example for the reordering of command definitions and desired output. What I want is that the numbers in these commands directly correspond to the position of the command definition.

Comment: I give up, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view, it's easier to contract the call to `\numberedcommand` from two calls into one and provide the macro names of `\initstate` and `\processstate as arguments.

Anyway, `\number\value{foo}` will evaluate the counter value and use it as an index. `\the\numexpr\value{foo}+1` will use the next integer value without really increasing the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{funcsyms}
\setcounter{funcsyms}{0}

\providecommand{\initstate}{f_}
\providecommand{\processstate}{f_}

\newcommand{\numberedcommand}[4]{%
  \renewcommand{#1}{#2{\number\value{#3}}}%
  \renewcommand{#4}{#2{\the\numexpr\value{#3}+1}}%
  \stepcounter{#3}
 }

\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{\processstate}

\begin{document}

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]


\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}{\processstate}


\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Edit with `\xdef` (although a little bit unsatisfactory)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{funcsyms}
\setcounter{funcsyms}{0}

\providecommand{\initstate}{f_}
\providecommand{\processstate}{f_}
\providecommand{\storestate}{f_}

\newcommand{\numberedcommand}[4]{%
  \stepcounter{#3}%
  \xdef#1{#2{\number\value{#3}}#4}
}

\numberedcommand{\storestate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\processstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}
\numberedcommand{\initstate}{f_}{funcsyms}{}

\begin{document}



\[\initstate(x,y,0) \to \storestate(x,y)\]

\[\initstate(x,y,z) \to \processstate(x,z)\]

\[\initstate(0,0,z) \to z\]

\[\storestate(x,y) \to \processstate(y,x)\]

\[\processstate(s(x),y) \to \initstate(x,x,y)\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: How would that work with more than two commands? I would like to have a generic method to define arbitrarily many commands. With your solution, I would have to change everything manually again if I insert a new command between the existing two, don't I?

Comment: @cryingshadow: Your question isn't really clear, I think. I can change, but I have other work to do

Comment: I tried to clarify the question by more examples. The essence is that if I have a command `\foo`, then I want the number used in the output of `\foo` to correspond to the position of the definition of `\foo`. So when `\foo` is the third command that I defined, the number should be 3. If it is the second command, it should be 2 etc.

Comment: @cryingshadow: I'll see what I can do

Comment: @cryingshadow: I've updated my answer (see at the bottom, please)

Comment: In the version posted by you, it did not work (e.g., `\tmpa` was not defined at all), but I could edit your code to make it work and do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @cryingshadow: Sorry, I changed the code before I posted. Thanks. I still don't understand what you design for the 4th. argument

Comment: In the given example, that is not really used, but in my document I also have things where the number is in between something. So the fourth argument allows me to put something behind the number.